# Can I enchant additional affixes or effects onto items?

Tags: diablo-iii

Now that the enchanter has become available with the Reaper of Souls expansion, I am wondering her capabilities. let's say for example I'm a Monk and have a rare item with the following effects:

Primary

- 400 Dexterity
- 400 Vitality
- Increases Critical Hit Chance by 7%

Secondary

- 90 Cold resistance
- 20% Gold from monsters

Can I add another primary effect to this item? Or am I limited to overwriting one of the effects it already has? I have seen rares with up to 6 effects in the past, is that simply something I'll have to get lucky on (regarding the base number of effects)?

Comment: Nope, currently the Mystic can just re-roll a single stat.  Kinda way too limiting, if you ask me.

Comment: @Frank not really, the whole point of the Mystic is to boost items that are close but useless to very good, and from very good to awesome. Not so you can take any piece of junk and make it awesome.

Comment: A helm with 7% crit chance?! Sign me up - it typically only rolls up to 6%.  ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  You can only reroll existing affixes into new affixes of the same category* (vit->armor).  I.e. you cannot roll a secondary affix into a primary affix.

There are some limitations for this rerolling:

- You cannot add a second affix that's existing on the item.  So no doubling up of Int affixes, for example.
- You cannot add a resist all or (specific resist) affix onto an item if the other exists already.  This is to prevent doubling up of resists (OWE nerf for monks basically)
- You can only add affixes that can be found naturally on the equipment slot.  Weapons will never roll +armor, for instance, and bracers will never have a socket.
- You cannot reroll specific legendary mods (The only one I know of so far is the increased fire damage taken on Andariel's helm).  You also can't reroll the orange stats, but that should be obvious.

Comment: Might want to clarify that you can reroll existing affixes into new, supposedly "equivalent" affixes that aren't the same (e.g. cold resist -> fire resist or such)

Comment: @Doc Are you sure it can't be the same?  I think I've rolled vit into higher vit before, and same for armor.

Comment: Oh, it definitely can be the same, I'm just saying it can also be different, you aren't locked into vit necessarily, you might be able to switch from vit (a primary) to atk speed or something (not actually sure if vit can switch to atk speed, but just an example)

Comment: @Doc yea, vit can switch to attack speed, did it for a pair of gloves.  I'll add the clarification in, thanks.

Comment: Isn't there also the restriction that once you re-roll a category "slot" that you can only ever re-roll that slot on that specific item? Additionally re-rolling anything makes the item account bound, but that is slightly outside the question.

Comment: @horatio yes, but that's pretty obvious from the in game enchanter.  Once you pick an affix to roll and do so, you will never be able to pick any other affix again.